# Redirect referrer header

Tags: php, http, http-headers

I have a login script in PHP, where I redirect clients to. When the client is logged in, I want to return the user to the page which 302 redirected him to the login page.

I want to keep the url as clean as possible (preferably, only /login), and I don't want to use cookies, like a session cookie.

I attempted to rely on `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERRER']`, but I have a problem that when I click a link that require login, the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERRER']` is set to the page where the link was clicked, not the destination page which is the one that sends the 302 redirect. (FF4)

If `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERRER']` isn't set (https, bookmark or whatever), then I clutter up the GET url with the return url (*/login/return/myurl*). For all other cases (where browser supplies HTTP_REFERRER on the request which redirects to /login), I really want to rely solely on the `$_SERVER['HTTP_HEADER']` to produce a clean url.

Is there any way to politely ask the browser to send 'correct' referrer using the redirect header, or am I stuck with clogging up the url for all redirects?

Comment: Don't rely on `HTTP_REFERER`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to ask browser for anything referrer-related.

If I were you, I'd won't redirect anyone anywhere but show login form right in place (on a template-driven site it's extremely easy), storing current location in a hidden field.

Comment: Wouldn't that pollute search engine results with login boxes?

Comment: @Jon search engines? Correct me if I wrong: in your current scenario a search engine being redirected to the login page and face the same login box and you see nothing wrong with it [apparently]. Whats wrong with the same login box but just without a redirect?

Comment: In my mind, you would have 10 pages with the excact same content - 10 hits in index, instead of 10 pages pointing to one page - E.G one page in index? Or am I wrong about this?

Comment: @Jon in my mind, if it's private area, no search engine shouldn't be allowed even to request this page. If it's public area with login option, I see no reason for redirecting anyone from this page.

Answer (score 0):

You have no way of specifying the URL that is sent in the `Referer` header. You have three options.

- Store the URL in a session.
- Store the URL in a cookie.
- Store the URL in a request parameter.

The request parameter is the most appropriate, because the user might have multiple windows open (that share the session and the cookies) and you can easily distinguish them.

Comment: There is not another redirect code that is better suited, so that the client is sending the HTTP_REFERRER of the actual referrer?

Comment: I know of no specification that would mandate such behavior. Also beware of the misspelling: the header that stores the referrer is called `Referer` and accessed using `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`.